# How do I paginate Firebase data in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android application, I require to show firebase data in a recycle view.In firebase tutorial, they said about load full data in a stretch and display in recycle view, but I need to paginate the data. How do we achieve this pagination in android?

Comment: Why do you feel like you need to paginate the data?

Comment: I want to load around ten thousand data in recycle view. It is a large amount and take much time load, so I want to load hundred at a time.

Comment: The topic of pagination and Firebase has been covered extensively in the past. Did you read those topics and try any of the answers suggested there? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination